# how to know which method of optimization is the right

Tags: r, r-portfolioanalytics

the package PortfolioAnalytics in R has four options for optimize.portfolio: "DEoptim", "random",
"ROI", "ROI old", "pso", "GenSA". How to know when to use one or another?